# How to Recognize the CommandName of a LinkButton Inside an ItemTemplate af a RadListBox

Tags: asp.net, telerik, itemtemplate, radlistbox

I added an itemtemplate to my radlistbox and also added one label and two linkbutton(s) in it ...
my radlistbox is like below :

```
<telerik:RadListBox ID="RadlbOfImageGroup" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" DataSortField="Title"
    DataSourceID="sdsImagesGroup" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="ID" Skin="BlackByMe"
    EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" Width="260px" Height="365px" EmptyMessage="no rec!"
    AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadlbOfImageGroup_SelectedIndexChanged"
    CausesValidation="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr style="width: 100%;">
                <td style="width: 64%;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitleOfIG" runat="server" CssClass="lbl_ListBox_IG_Title" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 18%; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEditIG" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                        CssClass="lb_ListBox_IG" OnClick="lbEditIG_Click">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 18%; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDeleteIG" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
                        CssClass="lb_ListBox_IG" OnClick="lbDeleteIG_Click">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

My Problem is how can I check the CommandName of LinkButtons in code above when I click on them?
(We don't have access to these LinkButtons in CodeBehind)

I know we do not need CommandName for those LinkButtons / I Just want to know is it possible to read them from codebehind?

Comment: Hi, what do you need the `CommandName` for?  I'm just wondering whether `OnCommand` would be a better option?

Comment: hi my dear friend / it's just a sample / for example how can i change the forecolor of all my LinkButtons from CodeBehind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code that has been introduced by telerik team :

```
protected void lbDeleteIG_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;
       if (btn.CommandName=="Delete")
       {
           Response.Write("Deleted");
       }
   }
```

Comment: Hello MoonLight, I am working on something like, a city listbox, a area listbox which shows area of selected city. Now I want edit the city or delete. From Above I cannot understand how you will delete or edit particular item. Can you please provide some code around it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a standard way of addressing this issue but it's what I use:

```
For Each item In RadlbOfImageGroup.Items
    Dim editbutton As HtmlGenericControl = item.findcontrol("lbEditIG")
    //Do something with editbutton.CommandName
    Dim deletebutton As HtmlGenericControl = item.findcontrol("lbDeleteIG")
    //Do something with deletebutton.CommandName
Next
```

The above example is in VB.Net but should translate fairly easily to C# if that's what you're using.